# Joomla 2.5 getUserStateFromRequest load error

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I was following [the example](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_custom_filters_to_component_admin) to implement custom filters in Joomla 2.5 admin component.

But I am  getting error at models `populateState` method:

> Call to undefined method
>   somecompModelsomecomp::getUserStateFromRequest().

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('administrator');
// Load the filter state.
$search = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.search', 'filter_search');
```

Error disappears if I call `getUserStateFromRequest` using `$app`:

```
$app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.search', 'filter_search');
```

So whats the problem? In default Joomla components I've seen that it use the same approach and it works. Maybe I miss something in my model class?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happened because `$app` is an object of your application class. As you defined it in your code.

`$app = JFactory::getApplication('administrator');`

and `getUserStateFromRequest` method is defind in that Application class.so you have to use it like this if you want to access this method.

```
$app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.search', 'filter_search');
```

And for your information `$this` variable is your local object.